# objected oriented programming in python

Tags: python, object, oop, multiple-inheritance

The following code incorrectly outputs 55.
what is the problem?

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.w = width
        self.h = height

    def area(self):
        return self.w * self.h

    def perimeter(self):
        return (self.w + self.h) * 2


class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, length):
        super().__init__(width=length, height=length)


class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, l, h):
        self.l = l
        self.h = h

    def area(self):
        return 0.5 * self.l * self.h


class Pyramid(Square, Triangle):    # multiple inheritance
    def __init__(self, base, height):
        Square.__init__(self, length=base)
        Triangle.__init__(self, l=base, h=height)

    def area(self):
        return Square.area(self) + 0.5 * Square.perimeter(self) * self.h


pyramid = Pyramid(3, 5)
print(pyramid.area())    # 3 * 3 + 0.5 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 39
```

I wrote the correct code as below.
But I want the Square object to inherit from the Rectangle object.

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.lenght = length

    def area(self):
        return self.lenght ** 2

    def perimeter(self):
        return 4 * self.lenght


class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, l, h):
        self.l = l
        self.h = h

    def area(self):
        return 0.5 * self.l * self.h


class Pyramid(Square, Triangle):    # multiple inheritance
    def __init__(self, base, height):
        Square.__init__(self, length=base)
        Triangle.__init__(self, l=base, h=height)
        print(Square.area(self))
        print(Square.perimeter(self))

    def area(self):
        return Square.area(self) + 0.5 * Square.perimeter(self) * self.h


pyramid = Pyramid(3, 5)
print(pyramid.area())
```

Comment: Is a pyramid a triangle? Is a pyramid a square?

Answer (score 0):

`Square.__init__` calls `Rectangle.__init__` and sets `w` and `h` to the same value (3). Then `Triangle.__init__` sets `self.h` to 5. So when your `Pyramid` tries to use `Rectangle` methods calculate sizes, it will be using 5 instead of 3 (which is what you would expect for a square of length 3). The independent `Square` methods don't have this problem because they are not trying to use `self.h`.

If you want to keep your variables safe from being affected by other classes in the hierarchy, you can prefix them with `__` (double underscore). That will prevent them being clobbered accidentally by other classes trying to use the same attribute names.

See [private variables in Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).

---

Alternatively, don't make Pyramid a subclass of your other shapes. I would not normally regard a pyramid as a kind of triangle and a kind of square.